# Multi-repository docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, microservices

I have two services, on two different GitLab repositories, deployed to the same host. I am currently using `supervisord` to run all of the services. The CI/CD for each repository pushes the code to the host.

I am trying to replace `supervisord` with Docker. What I did was the following:

1. Set up a `Dockerfile` for each service.
2. Created a third repository with only a `docker-compose.yml`, that runs `docker-compose up` in its CI to build and run the two services. I expect this repository to only be deployed once.

I am looking for a way to have the `docker-compose` automatically update when I deploy one of the two services.

**Edit:** Essentially, I am trying to figure out the best way to use `docker-compose` with a multi repository setup and one host.

My `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
    api:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir server "app:app" --timeout 120
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - redis
    celery-worker:
        build: .
        command: celery worker -A server.celery_config:celery
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - redis
    celery-beat:
        build: .
        command: celery beat -A server.celery_config:celery --loglevel=INFO
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - redis
    other-service:
        build: .
        command: python other-service.py
        volumes:
            - .:/other-service
        depends_on:
            - redis
```

Comment: Let the CI run `docker-compose pull` and what else is needed to deploy?

Comment: @KlausD. I thought about it, but I am trying to separate the logic of the "manager" from each "worker". I don't want `docker-compose` to be run from within the CI of the services (=workers). I want each service to be completely standalone, while having `docker-compose` stitch it all together, automatically.

Comment: The CI/CD pipelines should let you define 2 "upstream" jobs for the job that "deploys" the compose...

Comment: If you question is more CI/CD specific than Docker (Compose) specific you should at least name the CI/CD system you are using.

Comment: I am using GitLab, however I think I was a bit misunderstood. I want `docker-compose` to automatically update with new images/code that was pushed. If it can be done without using CI, it's fine by me.

Comment: How do you expect `docker-compose` to (1) know when something is pushed and (2) execute itself without CI?

Comment: 2) `docker-compose` is executed in the CI of the 3rd repository. I only expect to execute it once. 1) That's my question.

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to figure out the best way to use `docker-compose` with a multi repository setup and one host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're setting this up in the context of a CI system, the `docker-compose.yml` file should just run the images; it shouldn't also take responsibility for building them.

Do *not* overwrite the code in a container using `volumes:`.

You mention each service's repository has a `Dockerfile`, which is a normal setup.  Your CI system should run `docker build` there (and typically `docker push`).  Then your `docker-compose.yml` file just needs to mention the `image:` that the CI system builds:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
    api:
        image: "me/django:${DJANGO_VERSION:-latest}"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - redis
    celery-worker:
        image: "me/django:${DJANGO_VERSION:-latest}"
        command: celery worker -A server.celery_config:celery
        depends_on:
            - redis
```

I hint at `docker push` above.  If you're using Docker Hub, or a cloud-hosted Docker image repository, or are running a private repository, the CI system should run `docker push` after it builds each image, and (if it's not Docker Hub) the `image:` lines need to include the repository address.

The other important question here is what to do on rebuilds.  I'd recommend giving each build a unique Docker image tag, a timestamp or a source control commit ID both work well.  In the `docker-compose.yml` file I show above, I [use an environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) to specify the actual image tag, so your CI system can run

```
DJANGO_VERSION=20200113.1114 docker-compose up -d
```

Then Compose will know about the changed image tag, and will be able to recreate the containers based on the new images.

(This approach is highly relevant in the context of cluster systems like Kubernetes.  Pushing images to a registry is all but required there.  In Kubernetes changing the name of an `image:` triggers a redeployment, so it's also all but required to use a unique image tag per build.  Except that there are multiple and more complex YAML files, the overall approach in Kubernetes would be very similar to what I've laid out here.)

Comment: Very informative answer. When I run `docker-compose` with the environment variable, wouldn't it require me to run this command every time I push a new docker image, with different timestamps?

Comment: It requires _your CI system_ to run this command every time _it_ pushes a new Docker image, which should be very easy to script.

Comment: But it requires the CI of each service to do it. I want the services to be completely independent of the whole system, which means they shouldn't know about `docker-compose`. I guess it's not possible.

Comment: I would like to know your opinion about using [Watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower/issues/16) in order to achieve continuous automatic updates for `docker-compose` images instead of the CI running `docker-compose up`.